Slow query with like on Postgres 14.6
I have a table that contains ~ 100.000.000 records. In this table, there's a varchar(30) column that contains the license plates of cars. I'm joining this table with another table that contains the same amount of records.
I need to query this table using like with different values, and order the results using a column from the joined table:
   select *
     from tvxa.ttvx51_msg_81 as ttvx51
left join tvxa.ttvx63_ult_ric as fnl on ttvx51.c_id_msg = fnl.c_id_msg and fnl.c_tip_ric = ('FNL')
    where fnl.c_tar ilike any ('{"GD47%", "CD529%", "CX7530_", "GL573S_"}')
 order by ttvx51.d_trn desc
    limit 10 offset 0;

On the b.d_trn column, there's a standard index (btree) and on the a.c_tar column there's a gist and a standard btree index.
The c_id_msg columns are both the primary key of the two tables.
Here all the indexes created on the two tables:

I'm having performance problems only using some values on the like operation.
For example, using this query:
   select *
     from tvxa.ttvx51_msg_81 as ttvx51
left join tvxa.ttvx63_ult_ric as fnl on ttvx51.c_id_msg = fnl.c_id_msg and fnl.c_tip_ric = ('FNL')
    where fnl.c_tar ilike any ('{"AB142%"}')
 order by ttvx51.d_trn desc
    limit 10 offset 0;

it takes at least 20 minutes.
Performance seems very random, some values take milliseconds and some take minutes.
The only correlation that I saw is that the input that takes longer is composed of at least 5 characters with a % at the end of the string.
If I remove the order by clause, it takes only some seconds to perform the query.
Here are query planner results for the query with order by clause and 5 char of input:
Limit  (cost=1001.16..59950.24 rows=10 width=274)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.16..48020923.65 rows=8146 width=274)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..48018983.37 rows=3394 width=274)
              ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using ittvx51_msg_81_migrazione2 on ttvx51_msg_81 ttvx51  (cost=0.57..22944880.81 rows=37045867 width=204)
              ->  Index Scan using ittvx63_ult_ric_migrazione on ttvx63_ult_ric fnl  (cost=0.57..0.68 rows=1 width=70)
                    Index Cond: (c_id_msg = ttvx51.c_id_msg)
                    Filter: (((c_tar)::text ~~* ANY ('{AB142%}'::text[])) AND ((c_tip_ric)::text = 'FNL'::text))

With explain (buffers, analyze)
Limit  (cost=1001.16..59951.63 rows=10 width=274) (actual time=453151.960..612564.881 rows=10 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=291645856 read=1955824
  I/O Timings: read=1106382.770
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.16..48022052.31 rows=8146 width=274) (actual time=453151.958..612564.875 rows=10 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=291645856 read=1955824
        I/O Timings: read=1106382.770
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..48020112.04 rows=3394 width=274) (actual time=388428.681..554079.550 rows=5 loops=3)
              Buffers: shared hit=291645856 read=1955824
              I/O Timings: read=1106382.770
              ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using ittvx51_msg_81_migrazione2 on ttvx51_msg_81 ttvx51  (cost=0.57..22945552.81 rows=37045867 width=204) (actual time=0.057..49202.373 rows=16243236 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=48645632 read=645078
                    I/O Timings: read=91099.170
              ->  Index Scan using ittvx63_ult_ric_migrazione on ttvx63_ult_ric fnl  (cost=0.57..0.68 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=0 loops=48729709)
                    Index Cond: (c_id_msg = ttvx51.c_id_msg)
                    Filter: (((c_tar)::text ~~* ANY ('{AB142%}'::text[])) AND ((c_tip_ric)::text = 'FNL'::text))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                    Buffers: shared hit=243000224 read=1310746
                    I/O Timings: read=1015283.600
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=490
Planning Time: 0.595 ms
Execution Time: 612564.974 ms

Instead, there are query planner results for the query without order by clause and 5 char of input:
Limit  (cost=431.81..565.35 rows=10 width=274)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=431.81..109212.18 rows=8146 width=274)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ttvx63_ult_ric fnl  (cost=431.24..34898.28 rows=8687 width=70)
              Recheck Cond: ((c_tar)::text ~~* ANY ('{AB142%}'::text[]))
              Filter: ((c_tip_ric)::text = 'FNL'::text)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ittvx63_ult_ric_3  (cost=0.00..429.07 rows=9153 width=0)
                    Index Cond: ((c_tar)::text ~~* ANY ('{AB142%}'::text[]))
        ->  Index Scan using ttvx51_msg_81_migrazione_pkey_migrazione on ttvx51_msg_81 ttvx51  (cost=0.57..8.55 rows=1 width=204)
              Index Cond: (c_id_msg = fnl.c_id_msg)

With explain (buffers, analyze)
Limit  (cost=435.81..569.35 rows=10 width=274) (actual time=253353.646..253361.341 rows=10 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=830 read=300091
  I/O Timings: read=249287.405
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=435.81..109216.18 rows=8146 width=274) (actual time=253353.644..253361.334 rows=10 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=830 read=300091
        I/O Timings: read=249287.405
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ttvx63_ult_ric fnl  (cost=435.24..34902.28 rows=8687 width=70) (actual time=253352.990..253354.078 rows=10 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((c_tar)::text ~~* ANY ('{AB142%}'::text[]))
              Filter: ((c_tip_ric)::text = 'FNL'::text)
              Heap Blocks: exact=10
              Buffers: shared hit=789 read=300082
              I/O Timings: read=249280.389
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ittvx63_ult_ric_3  (cost=0.00..433.07 rows=9153 width=0) (actual time=253351.558..253351.558 rows=49 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((c_tar)::text ~~* ANY ('{AB142%}'::text[]))
                    Buffers: shared hit=786 read=300066
                    I/O Timings: read=249278.022
        ->  Index Scan using ttvx51_msg_81_migrazione_pkey_migrazione on ttvx51_msg_81 ttvx51  (cost=0.57..8.55 rows=1 width=204) (actual time=0.720..0.720 rows=1 loops=10)
              Index Cond: (c_id_msg = fnl.c_id_msg)
              Buffers: shared hit=41 read=9
              I/O Timings: read=7.016
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=1157 read=3
  I/O Timings: read=3.113
Planning Time: 5.534 ms
Execution Time: 253361.759 ms

And last, here are query planner results for the query with order by clause and 3 char of input:
Limit  (cost=1001.16..59950.24 rows=10 width=274)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.16..48020923.65 rows=8146 width=274)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..48018983.37 rows=3394 width=274)
              ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using ittvx51_msg_81_migrazione2 on ttvx51_msg_81 ttvx51  (cost=0.57..22944880.81 rows=37045867 width=204)
              ->  Index Scan using ittvx63_ult_ric_migrazione on ttvx63_ult_ric fnl  (cost=0.57..0.68 rows=1 width=70)
                    Index Cond: (c_id_msg = ttvx51.c_id_msg)
                    Filter: (((c_tar)::text ~~* ANY ('{AB142%}'::text[])) AND ((c_tip_ric)::text = 'FNL'::text))

Is there a way to improve performance for this type of query? Am I doing something wrong?
I've tried to add different indexes with different algorithms but the results seem the same.

could you try with exaplain (buffers, analyze). It'll provide more information

and some basic recommendations, have you tried vacuum analyze for this tables? Is limit make difference? If you'll set SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0; then the last query (3chars) would be so long as 5 chars with similar plan?

First you can decompose array search into four separate searches. Then, it's easier to optimize a.c_tar = 'AB142%' as lower(a.c_tar) = lower('AB142%').

@AlexeyStepanov I haven't tried the vacuum analysis. I've tried with a limit (the original query uses a limit of 10) but with the same results.

@AlexeyStepanov just edited with the explain (buffers, analyze) results

It seems that you manipulated the plans or the queries somehow. Your question joins a and b, but the execution plan joins b and b. That is confusing, and so I cannot answer the question. Please show us the actual query and the actual execution plan. If you manipulate them, only modify names, and be consistent about it.

@LaurenzAlbe sorry for that, I've only changed the table names but I've made a mistake in one of them. Just correct it on the question.

You do have an index on b.id  (or b.c_id_msg if that is the name of the column... ) ?  (The tag: [tag:sql] says "Questions should include .... table structure...." )

b.c_id_msg is the primary key of the table so yes there's a unique index on that. The c_id_msg columns are of type uuid. The date column is of type timestamp and there's a btree index on that, and the license_plate column is of type varchar(30) and there are two indexes as described in the question.

Not good enough. You call both indexes index_btree. But they cannot have the same name. We also need to know on which columns these indexes are. Do yourself a favor and post the actual, unedited plan. Don't tell me your table names contain secrets...

You seem to acknowledge that an index on b.c_id_msg is missing....

No table names does not contain secrets :D Just updated

Please take a look at: How to list indexes created for table in postgres

Most of this sad tale is contained in the bitmap line from one of the plans:
expected rows=9153, actual rows = 49. So the row estimate is off by about 200 fold.  This means that by walking the index backward to fulfill the ORDER BY, it thinks it can find 10 rows and then stop after doing 200 times less work than it actually can.  While the plan is should be using, fetching all 49 rows and sorting them, it thinks will be 200 times more work than it actually is.  These two mistakes compound, so overall it misestimating the plan costs by about 40,000 fold. Not surprisingly, this leads to the wrong plan being selected.
There is not much you can do about the row estimate. PostgreSQL has no way to know how many rows will actually match the rare LIKE condition.  There is a big difference between the assumed 0.0001 selectivity and real 5e-7 selectivity and currently implemented statistics can't help improve that decision.  I do have ideas for improving this for the specific case of LIKE/~~, but I don't see those ideas getting implemented soon or ever, and likely to open a whole new can of worms. (Basically have the planner keep shortening the pattern until it finds at least one match in the statistical sample with the shortened pattern, and then use the number of trimmed off characters to extrapolate the real selectivity downward).
You could force it to use the correct plan in two ways.  One is to use a MATERIALIZED CTE to force it to fetch all rows meeting the where clause up front, and then apply the sort and the limit outside the CTE.  The other is to change the ORDER BY in a way which defeats the index usage while not changing the result, ORDER BY d_trn + interval '0' desc.  But this will force it to use that plan even when it is not the best one, e.g. when the pattern is very unselective. So you might need to detect the pattern length on the client side and make the client choose between which way to formulate the query for best execution.
As a side note, the better plan would probably be much better yet with a GIN index rather than a GiST index for the trigrams.  But that isn't going to change the planning issues.

Good comment. I wish I had time to focus in the PostgreSQL internals; it was fun (?) well, for me, yeah.

@TheImpaler, great answers. Thanks. I already tested with MATERIALIZED CTE, which slightly improved the performance (from several minutes, it takes 40 / 60 seconds). I will try the GIN index instead of the GiST index

Try with CTE, so sort should be cheaper eg:
 WITH mydata AS (SELECT a.*,b.date AS bdate 
   FROM a left join b on a.c_id_msg = b.c_id_msg
   WHERE a.c_tar ilike any ('{"AB142%"}') )
 SELECT mydata.* FROM mydata ORDER BY mydata.bdate;


Most likely, you need to MATERIALIZE the CTE. Otherwise, there is a good chance you get exactly the same query plan as the original query.

Thanks! Seems working. Just trying with different inputs to see if it resolves the problems for all possible values.

I just re-tried and I've got the same problems. It seems very random, even with the same input, sometimes takes seconds, and sometimes takes 20 minutes.

@MarioAgati Did you try it with MATERIALIZED as Frank suggested?

Unfortunately, I can't materialize it as the two tables have a lot of changes

@MarioAgati MATERIALIZED is a keyword you attach to a CTE query.  It is an instruction to the planner.  It is not the same thing as a materialized view.  WITH mydata AS MATERIALIZED (...

Sorry @jjanes I didn't know the materialized keyword on the CTE. Thanks for that. Unfortunately, this seems very performant where the like input is 4 or more characters, but very slow when I've fewer characters or more inputs. The more inputs I add the more slower the query is.
